# How can I disable parent background div when a child container div is active?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I want to disable a **parent background div which contains grid with data**. On the grid there are options like sorting and exporting the data into `csv/pdf`. Also, on this grid there is a filter button, on click of which(via `ng-click= xyz();`) a filter overlay comes. This is a child container `div` inside the parent `div`. I want to disable the parent grid div when this filter overlay `div` opens i.e., disable the sorting and export and any other functionalities on the parent `div`.

Any help form anyone? My entire project is in `angular js`. An example with a demo will be great!

**In agg.service.js**

```
angular.module('ccar14a.common').factory('ccar14a.common.AggService', [
'ccar14a.common.Config',
'StatusService',
'ccar14a.common.TcnService',
'ccar14a.common.PivotService',
'ccar14a.common.GridConfigService',
'$timeout',
function(Config, StatusService, TcnService, PivotService, GridConfigService, $timeout) {

    var service = { 
            openFilterOverlay: function() {
            console.log("Toggle Filter overlay00");

           var filteroverlay = angular.element(".filter-overlay");

           if(filteroverlay.hasClass('open')) {

               filteroverlay.removeClass('open');
           } else {
               filteroverlay.addClass('open');
           }
            angular.element('.tooltip').hide();
        },
   };

    return service;
   }]);
```

In **index.html**

```
<div class="col-md-12 main-view" ng-controller="ccar14a.common.drillDownController">

<div class="ddt-container">
    <h2>
    <span>
        {{config.title}} v{{config.version}}.
        <a href="" ng-click="getInitialFilter(true)"
                    ng-disabled="aggService.gridDisconnected" ng-if="config.initialTitle">
            {{config.initialTitle}}</a>
        <!--<span class="pull-right" style="font-size: 10px">, RDA: {{config.rda}}</span>-->
        <!--<span class="pull-right" style="font-size: 10px">Bridge: {{config.bridge | bridgeDomain}}</span>-->
    </span>
    <div class="ddt-links pull-right">
        <a href="" ng-click="about()">
            About</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="help()">
            Help</a>
    </div>
</h2>
</div>

<!--div container for filter overlay starts here-->

<div class="container-fluid ddt-container" ng-controller="ccar14a.common.drillDownController" id="ccar14a">
    <h2 ng-hide="true" class="remove">
    <span>
        {{config.title}} v{{config.version}}.
        <a href="" ng-click="getInitialFilter(true)"
                    ng-disabled="aggService.gridDisconnected" ng-if="config.initialTitle">
            {{config.initialTitle}}</a>
        <!--<span class="pull-right" style="font-size: 10px">, RDA: {{config.rda}}</span>-->
        <!--<span class="pull-right" style="font-size: 10px">Bridge: {{config.bridge | bridgeDomain}}</span>-->
    </span>
    <div class="ddt-links pull-right">
        <a href="" ng-click="about()">
            About</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="help()">
            Help</a>
    </div>
</h2>


    <div class="ddt-sidebar filter-overlay col-md-2">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group ddt-filter-box-group">
                    <select class="form-control ddt-filter-box-fld" ng-model="savedFilter" ng-change="aggService.submitScenario(filter)">
                        <option value="">My Saved Filters</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="button" class="filter-close close-filter pull-right" ng-click="aggService.openFilterOverlay()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove filter-close"></i></button>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!--The code continues having several filter box  -->
 <div class="ddt-content col-xs-12" ng-class="{'col-md-10': !showControlPanel, 'col-xs-12' : !showControlPanel}">
            <div class="ddt-grid" ng-controller="ccar14a.common.AggController" ng-show="config.displaySummaryGrid">
                <ng-include src="'templates/summaryGrid.html' | embedUrl"></ng-include>
</div>
```

In **summaryGrid.html**

```
<div class="grid-header">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm ddt-btn-medium pull-left" ng-show="true" ng-click="aggService.openFilterOverlay();">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" tooltip="Open Filter" tooltip-placement="right"></i>
</button>
<!-- Code for other functionalities continues-->
</div>
```

In **styles.css**

```
.filter-overlay {
position: absolute;
left: -500px;
background: #EEE;
transition: 1s;
z-index: 1000;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 3px #aaaaaa;
height: 100%;
min-width:365px;
overflow-y: auto;
 }

.filter-overlay.open {
transition: 1s;
left: 0;
}

.filter-overlay .row {
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-top: 8px;
margin-botton: 12px;}

.container-fluid {
background-color: #F0F3F6;
height: 100%;
padding: 18px;}

.container-fluid .row{
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;}

.ddt-content {
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
background-color: white;}

.tab-content > .tab-pane {
display: none;}

.tab-content > .active {
display: block;}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the code or add a fiddle?

Comment: "An example with a demo will be great!" I completely agree, you first!

Comment: As others have said, nobody can help you properly without seeing the relevant code but one thing that might work for you is setting the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) of the parent to `none` and then resetting that property to `initial` on the child element. Be sure to check [browser support for `pointer-events`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) first.

Comment: @TirthrajBarot I have uploaded the code for reference with images.

Comment: @DBS now you can refer.

Comment: @Shaggy I have uploaded the code for reference with images.

Answer (score 2):

If you disable the parent element then obviously the children elements will also be disabled. Instead of making them parent and children you can place those two divs as siblings and hide them individually depending on the visibility of the element.

Comment: Yeah!. You are right but my project structure is like that only. I have to work according to the structure. I have uploaded the code and images . Please check

Comment: I don't think its not possible.

But you can use JS to clone the element or pull it our and play around.

In JQuery you can clone/copy a element.

`var element = jQuery('.Inner-Div').clone();`

and then append to any visible element that be appropriate.

`element.appendTo('some element');`